# C# SqlStoredProc

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

What is the difference between `SqlValue` and `Value`?

```
sproc.Parameters
    .Add(@ColumnName.USERNAME, SqlDbType.NVarChar, 64).SqlValue = Username;
```

and

```
sproc.Parameters
    .Add(@ColumnName.USERNAME, SqlDbType.NVarChar, 64).Value = Username;
```

Does `SqlValue` resolve the type for the database faster than `Value`?

Comment: Sorry - what's `**SqlValue**` supposed to be?

Comment: I was trying to place a bold around SqlValue.

Comment: @Yuck Bold **SqlValue**.

Comment: did you cut and paste the same thing..? I don't see a difference in the difference you are in question about....

Comment: @DJKRAZE one uses .SqlValue and the other uses .Value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SqlValue is the SQL Server type, while Value is the .NET type.  For example, if you set the value to null, the equivelent in SqlValue is DBNull.Value.

As for whether it's faster, it would probably be slightly faster, because there is no conversion from .NET type to SqlDbType, but this difference is likely negligable, and would likely get eaten up in you converting the type to SqlDbType in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, So SqlValue would send the type to the SQL server. and as a result it would execute much faster. Because the SQL server doesn't need to resolve the type.

Comment: I agree, but having c# convert the type would be much faster than the sql database resolving the type?

Comment: @James - I didn't say "much" faster.  It might be slightly faster, and any benefit would be very small, if at all noticable.

Comment: `DBNull` must be used with `Value` as well.

Answer (score 0):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.sqlvalue.aspx)

> Gets or sets the value of the parameter as an SQL type.

You should probably stick to Value.